# $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ implies $f_n (A)$ converges to $f(A)$ in operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

$A$ is a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space such that $aI\le A \le bI$. $f_n$ is a monotonic decreasing sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$. I need to show that $f_n (A)$ converges to $f(A)$ in operator norm.

For that I of course need to show that the fact that $\mathrm {sup}|f_n (t)-f(t)|\rightarrow0$, implies that $\mathrm {sup}_{||x||=1}||f_n (A)x-f(A)x||\rightarrow0$, but my attemps were unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $A$ here?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: What is the underlying space on which $A$ operates? How is $f(A)$ defined for a given function?

Comment: Your functions $f_n$ are real-valued, what does $f_n(A)$ mean? If $A$ is an operator on the set fo continuous functions on $[a,b]$, you should note $A(f_n)$. And what is $aI$ and $bI$?

Comment: If $g$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then there is a monotonic decresing sequence of polynomials $q_n$ that converges to $g$. Now $g(A)$ is defined as the strong limit of $q_n (A)$ (and this is well defined).

Comment: Is $A$ an operator on a Banach space or on a Hilbert space? If its on a Banach space how are you defining $aI≤A≤bI$?

Comment: Yes on a Hilbert space. I've edited the question.

Comment: Have you seen the functional calculus? Esp. the Gelfand transform?

Comment: No. I've seen several basic theorems regarding operators defined by functions, but definitely not calculus.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense after your edits, and after you added in a comment how you want to define $f(A)$ at all, _though that information should be in the question, not in a comment_. Why do I emphasize this? It shows your reasoning is in a sense circular: to justify your definition of $f(A),$ you need your claim, at least for the case where $f_n$ are polynomials. Please, unfold your "and this is well defined", and look how that extends to functions just approximated by polynomials!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf {Theorem:}$ $f,g$ are two upper semi-continuous functions on $[a,b]$. If $f(t)\le g(t)$ for all $t\in [a,b]$, then $f(A)\le g(A)$ for $A$ a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space such that $aI\le A \le bI$.

$\mathbf {Lemma:}$ If $A$ is a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space such that $-cI\le A\le cI$ for $c$ real, then $||A||\le c$ (in operator norm).

Now, since $f_n$  is a monotonic decreasing sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, we know that $f_n (A)\rightarrow f(A)$ strongly. Moreover, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ and for all $t\in [a,b]$ we have $f(t)-\epsilon\le f_n (t)\le f(t)+\epsilon$.
From the theorem we get that $-\epsilon I\le f_n (A)-f(A)\le \epsilon I$ and from the lemma we get $||f_n (A)-f(A)||\le\epsilon$ as required.